# C# Pattern for aggregating interface methods into one generic method

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns, reflection

I'm searching for a pattern to aggregate interface methods into one generic method.

Better to make an example of what I'm trying to do

Consider that I have an interface with more then 40 methods which have all different responsibilities but the implementations of these methods are equal besides of function name an parameters.

```
interface MultiMethod{
   public TypeA A (p1,p2);
   public TypeA B (p1);
   public TypeC C (p5,p3,p2);
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Implementation Class

```
class MultiMethodeService : MultiMethod
```

In the MultiMethodeService I need to Implement all Interface methods, but the implementation of the methods is not real different.

Like:

```
public TypeA A (p1,p2){
   proxy.call("remoteA").params(p1,p2);
}
public TypeB B (p1){
   proxy.call("remoteB").params(p1);
}
```

I want to replace the implementation of the methods with one generic method that uses reflection.

The generic method derives

- the parameters form the MultiMethod interface
- the method name from the MultiMethode interface to invoke the equal proxy call

For me it is clear how implement the generic method, but how is it possible, when I have a generic method to also have the equal semantic like without a generic implementation.Deeper meaning code complition (intellisense) should work for the generic implementation equal to the OOP implementation.
When I afterwords want to use the service object of MultiMethodService like :

```
var service = new MultiMethodService()
service.A(p1,p2)
```

Some naive idea was to implement an enum{"A","B"}

```
service.callGeneric(enum.A, p1,p2);
service.callGeneric(enum.B, p1);
```

which is not really nice.

Again why would you implement this an not the straight forward OOP solution?

- Prevent implementing the same method again and again with only a few changes that could be deduced by reflection from an interface
- DRY, Don't reaped yourself. If the interface changes or parameter types, only refactor these but not the whole remote calls (interface implementation)

If you could provide any pattern or idea, your help is highly appreciated.

**offtopic**
More explanation needed? Lets say I have this javascript (typescript)  [interface](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/services/services.ts#L876) in c# which represents the typescript service to c#. Additionally I have the [c# classes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/services/services.ts#L16) reflecting the javascript classes. Now I have an mechanism to call from C# into javascript to compute the result. [see here](https://gist.github.com/chrisber/789d59372e9b41e657d9). Which is implemented in the interface methods. This repeats 46 times, and if something changes I have to refactor some of the implementation. How can I prevent reimplementing the inteface methods by using something generic. With the possibility to use afterwords the service like `service.getSyntacticDiagnostics(...)`, I can rephrase this with, code completion(intellisense) should work equally to OOP style code.

Comment: My first thought is why do you want to do this. Would it be better to organize your program some other way? I'm not sure I see the big idea of what you want to do here. Do you just want to throw parameters at the service and let the service figure out what to do with them?

Comment: @chessofnerd I think OP tries to simplify manually writing code similar to what "add service reference" would auto-generate - strongly typed façade for remote service call.

Comment: +1 @ Alexei. Karl, you are probably looking at code auto-generation. You could write your own script with reflection (powerhsell/c#) or use T4 templates and do the code generation.

Comment: Yes, I think this is a way to go, and I will use it as the solution. But now I'm really curios about if there exists  solution about what I'm trying to do.